# Determine why Windows Hello is unavailable on a Surface Book

Tags: windows, windows-10, microsoft-surface

My group has several Surface Books. We bought some of them a little under a year ago and we just bought a second round last month.

The first group are all set up to use Windows Hello w/ Facial Recognition. It works beautifully.

For the second group, Windows Hello setup is disabled on the Sign-In Options page.

All of the computers - first and second group - are on our domain.

- It could be group policy... but why would it only impact the second
  group? And I checked all of the Windows Hello for Business settings
  in gpedit, but they're all "Not Configured"
- It could be a hardware issue... but seems strange it would impact several devices all at the same time.
- It could be some other setting I'm unaware of.

So how can I troubleshoot this? How can I determine why the Set Up button under Face Recognition on the Sign-in Options page is disabled?

Comment: The first step, in order determine the cause of this behavior, is to change the Windows Hello group policy so it's specifically enabled.  There are polcies where "not configured" is "disabled" and others it's "enabled".  So let's rule out that possability.  The computers in the first group, their domain account, are they linked to a MS account?  Yes;  *that question does make sense.*

Comment: Microsoft changed the framework Windows Hello runs on for Domain-joined computer in the Anniversary Update. This also means new policies to be configured on the Domain. If a computer had Hello enabled prior to the update, Hello will continue working as before. If the computer is updated before a user sets up Hello, those new policies need to be configured on the domain before it'll work again. Good thing: The new framework is much more secure. Bad thing: this sort of thing.

Comment: Things your IT department needs to read: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/ash/2016/08/13/changes-to-convenience-pin-and-thus-windows-hello-behaviour-in-windows-10-version-1607/ and https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/itpro/windows/keep-secure/implement-microsoft-passport-in-your-organization and https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/itpro/windows/keep-secure/manage-identity-verification-using-microsoft-passport

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft changed how Windows Hello worked on Domain-joined computers with build 1607, the "Anniversary Update".

Previously, Windows Hello on a business computer worked pretty much the same as it did on a home computer. It was more or less a stored password that was "triggered" by the chosen acceptable authentication methods.

Now it is based on certificates and other things that are generally much more secure.

If no changes are made in Group Policy on the Domain, a computer had an earlier build (such as 1511) of Windows 10 and a user had configured Windows Hello, and then the computer was updated to build 1607, that same user would still be able to use the same Windows Hello authentication methods. Any users trying to set up Windows Hello for the first time post-upgrade or just on build 1607 would not be able to.

The domain administrators must configure the new Group Policies controlling Windows Hello for Business before any of the authentication methods will work on computers running Windows 10 build 1607.

For more information and for the specific settings that must be set, please read the following official documents from Microsoft:

- [Implement Windows Hello for Business in your organization](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/itpro/windows/keep-secure/implement-microsoft-passport-in-your-organization) - This is the functional document with a list of the new policies and what their settings mean.
- [Manage identity verification using Windows Hello for Business](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/itpro/windows/keep-secure/manage-identity-verification-using-microsoft-passport) - This is more of an overview and includes information about the differences between the home and enterprise versions of Windows Hello.
- [Changes to Convenience PIN / Windows Hello Behavior in Windows 10 Version 1607](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/ash/2016/08/13/changes-to-convenience-pin-and-thus-windows-hello-behaviour-in-windows-10-version-1607/) - This is a blog article about the major differences and may be helpful for users trying to understand what has happened and why.

Comment: Thanks @music2myear that is almost certainly the problem here. One follow-up question on this. Is it enough to (as a local administrator) change the "Turn on convenience PIN sign-in" policy to Enabled in gpedit? Or does it have to be done at the domain level and pushed down?

Comment: If the Domain policy is set to "Not Configured" (that is the typical default) then any local policy will be applied. Domain policy always supersedes local policy, but only where it is actually configured.

Comment: As I point out.  "not configured" could mean "allow" or "deny" all depends on the default value of the policy is.

Comment: Setting it to Enabled locally worked fine on one of our test machines. So it looks like this is a good workaround until our central IT can get the rest setup. Thanks!

Comment: Coolbeans. @Ramhound "Not Configured" does sometimes have a default position, but it also means that if a policy in a different place has a setting besides Not Configured, that policy will supersede. Basically, Not Configured allow the default behavior in the OS to proceed and in the GP itself there is no record of that setting. So a Domain GP with Not Configured will have nothing to overwrite even a non-default Local GP.

Comment: Oh I know.  I have to deal with stuff like this weekly.  Takes forever to jump through The hoops

Comment: This one stuck out to me because we were using Hello for fingerprint access on the 1511 build systems, and then found that while machines we upgraded in place to 1607 could still use fingerprints on the user accounts that had already set them up, all others couldn't.